# Report from Dart tree shaker?

Tags: dart

What I need from the report is paths to symbols that were retained after the tree shaking, so I can identify design flaws that cause the code size to increase without a good reason, similar to SOYC in GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the answer from Peter Ahé](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/compiler-dev/6CGVNHTfQNc/5PCpeaGDumAJ) :

> We don't have such a tool yet, but it something that we would like to
>   provide at some point. See http://dartbug.com/9876.
>
> I think a tool like that might emerge as we start tackling fast
>   incremental compilations.  This requires tracking dependencies more
>   carefully than we do today, and those dependencies will be the base
>   for the report you're looking for.